# Jquery slidetoogle multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've the following function to toogle a div which is working fine. The problem is that I would like to use the same function to other divs without having to create multiple ids. How can this be done?

This is the code that I'm using:

```
$('#toggle1').click(function() {
    $('.toggle1').toggle();
    return false;
});
```

This is my HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="toggle1">Simple Div Toggle</a><br /><br />
<div class="toggle1" style="display:none;">Hello</div>
```

Comment: What is .toggle1? can you show your html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('[id^=toggle]').on('click', function(){
    $('.'+this.id).toggle();    // Thanks to Joe

});
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/7EY7F/2/

and with multi div : http://jsfiddle.net/7EY7F/3/

Comment: +1 - nice solution. Only one small thing - you could use `this.id` instead of `$(this).attr('id')`.